# Jacobian criterion for algebraic independence over a perfect field in positive characteristics

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

It is well known that the Jacobian criterion for algebraic independence does not hold in general for fields of positive characteristics. However, the following partial statement seems promising:

- Consider the polynomial algebra $\mathbb{F}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, where $\mathbb{F}$ be a perfect field of characteristic $p>0$, i.e., for all $a\in\mathbb{F}$, the equation $x^p=a$ has a solution. (For instance, $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{F}_p$.) Let $\varphi_1,\cdots,\varphi_m\in\mathbb{F}[x_1,\cdots,x_n], m\leq n$ be polynomials such that the Jacobian matrix $(\partial\varphi_j/\partial x_i)$ is of rank $m$. Then $\varphi_1,\cdots,\varphi_m$ are algebraically independent.

The argument is as follows. Suppose $\varphi_1,\cdots,\varphi_m$ are algebraically dependent. Let $f(y_1,\cdots,y_m)$
be the nontrivial polynomial of the lowest degree such that we have
$$f(\varphi_1,\cdots,\varphi_m)=0.$$
Since the Jocobian matrix is of full rank, we have $\partial f/\partial\varphi_i=0$ for all $i$. Therefore, we have
$$f(\varphi_1,\cdots,\varphi_m)=g(\varphi_1^p,\cdots,\varphi_m^p)$$
for some polynomial
$$g(z_1,\cdots,z_m)=\Sigma_{i_1,\cdots,i_m}a_{i_1,\cdots i_m}z_1^{i_1}\cdots z_m^{i_m}.$$
Let $b_{i_1,\cdots,i_m}\in\mathbb{F}$ satisfy $b_{i_1,\cdots,i_m}^p=a_{i_1,\cdots,i_m}$, and let
$$\bar{g}(w_1,\cdots w_m)=\Sigma_{i_1,\cdots,i_m}b_{i_1,\cdots i_m}w_1^{i_1}\cdots w_m^{i_m}\neq0.$$
Then we have
$$0=f(\varphi_1,\cdots,\varphi_m)=g(\varphi_1^p,\cdots,\varphi_m^p)=\Sigma_{i_1,\cdots,i_m}(b_{i_1,\cdots i_m}\varphi_1^{i_1}\cdots \varphi_m^{i_m})^p=\bar{g}(\varphi_1,\cdots,\varphi_m)^p.$$
Therefore, $\bar{g}(\varphi_1,\cdots,\varphi_m)=0$ is a nontrivial polynomial relation for $\varphi_1,\cdots,\varphi_m$, and the polynomial $\bar{g}$ has degree lower than that of $f$, a contradiction. Therefore, $\varphi_1,\cdots,\varphi_m$ are algebraically independent.

My questions are:  Am I missing anything in the above argument? If not, is it discussed anywhere in the literature?

Comment: A quick google search shows: https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/nitin/papers/wittJacobian.pdf

Comment: As for your proof, how do you go from $f(\varphi_1,\dots\varphi_m) = 0$ to $f = g^p$?

Comment: I haven't checked your proof, but the statement is true. The usual statement is that the Jacobian matrix has rank $m$ if and only if $(\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_m)$ is contained in a separating transcendence basis. In particular, this implies that  $(\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_m)$ is contained in a transendence basis, and thus are algebraically independent. My usual reference for these things is Eisenbud, <i>Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry</i>, Chapter 16.5 and Appendix I.

Comment: @ David E Speyer Thank you. In your statement, is the base field perfect?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer - I second the previous comment. Over an imperfect field, does full-rank Jacobian imply algebraic independence?

Comment: @mr_e_man Yes, this is correct for an imperfect base field. See my answer below.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer be careful with Appendix I of Eisenbud; it contains some mistakes/circular reasoning around the definitions of separable and separably generated extensions (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: Thanks for the warning. Any more details? @R.vanDobbendeBruyn

Comment: Looking back at my scribblings, maybe I'm just being thick. But I couldn't exactly figure out what's going on: the proof of A1.3d$\Rightarrow$a looks more like a proof of b$\Rightarrow$a (?), and I have no idea how the final statement of A1.6 is supposed to be proven (separably generated implies separable). The definitions actually agree with the Stacks project, where a full proof does appear (Tag [030X](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/030X)).

Comment: So my first comment turns out to be an overstatement, but there are definitely some issues with Appendix I in Eisenbud.

Answer (score 4):

The question is raised in comments about whether full rank Jacobian still implies algebraic independence in characteristic $p$ when the group field is imperfect. The answer is yes. Here is a reference, and a short proof.

**Reference** Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p$, let $K = k(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and let $F = k(f_1, \ldots, f_n) \subseteq K$. Then $dx_1$, $dx_2$, ..., $dx_n$ is a basis for $\Omega_{K/k}$ as a $K$-vector space. We have $df_j = \sum \tfrac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i} d x_i$, so the Jacobian matrix expresses the $df_j$ as $K$-linear combinations of the basis $d x_i$, and thus the Jacobian matrix has full rank if and only if the $df_j$ are a $K$-basis for $\Omega_{K/k}$.

Theorem 16.14 in Eisenbud, *Commutative Algebra with a View toward Algebraic Geometry* tells us that $df_j$ are a $K$-basis for $\Omega_{K/k}$ if and only the $df_i$ form a separating transcendence basis for $K/k$ (meaning that the $f_j$ are a transcendence basis for $F$ and $K/F$ is separable). In particular, it implies that the $f_j$ are a transcendence basis for the field $F$ that they generate, and thus they are linearly independent.

**Quick Proof** Suppose for contradiction that the Jacobian matrix is invertible and we have an algebraic relation $g(f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n) = 0$ for some polynomial $g(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n)$. Take $g$ of minimal total degree.

Now, applying the chain rule to the equation $g(f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n) = 0$, we get
$\begin{bmatrix} \tfrac{\partial g}{\partial z_j} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \tfrac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i} \end{bmatrix}=0$. Since we assumed that the Jacobian $\begin{bmatrix} \tfrac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i} \end{bmatrix}$ is invertible, this means that $\tfrac{\partial g}{\partial z_1}=\tfrac{\partial g}{\partial z_2}=\cdots = \tfrac{\partial g}{\partial z_n}=0$. This means that $g$ is a polynomial in $z_1^p$, $z_2^p$, ..., $z_n^p$, say $\sum g_{i_1 i_2 \cdots i_n} z_1^{pi_1} z_2^{p i_2} \cdots z_n^{p i_n}$. However, we don't know that the coefficients $ g_{i_1 i_2 \cdots i_n}$ are $p$-th powers. Presumably, this is where the commenters got stuck.

A little trick can unstick us. Consider $k$ as a $k^p$ vector space, so $k^p$ is a one-dimensional subspace of $k$. Choose a $k^p$-linear retraction $\lambda: k \to k^p$. (By a retraction, I mean that $\lambda(a^p) = a^p$ for $a^p \in k^p$.) Define $\lambda : k[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \to k^p[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ by acting on the coefficients. Now, apply the map $\lambda$ to the equation $\sum g_{i_1 i_2 \cdots i_n} f_1^{p i_1} f_2^{p i_2} \cdots f_n^{p i_n} = 0$. Each of the polynomials $f_j^{p i_j}$ is already in $k^p[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, so we get $\sum \lambda(g_{i_1 i_2 \cdots i_n}) f_1^{p i_1} f_2^{p i_2} \cdots f_n^{p i_n} = 0$. Moreover, replacing $g$ by $ag$ for some $a \in k$, we may assume that some coefficient of $g$ is equal to $1$, and hence the $\lambda(g_{i_1 i_2 \cdots i_n})$ are not all $0$.

So we get a new algebraic relation $\sum \lambda(g_{i_1 i_2 \cdots i_n}) f_1^{p i_1} f_2^{p i_2} \cdots f_n^{p i_n} = 0$ between the $f_j$'s. But now all the coefficients $\lambda(g_{i_1 i_2 \cdots i_n})$ are in $k^p$, so we may take a $p$-th root and get an algebraic relation $\sum \lambda(g_{i_1 i_2 \cdots i_n})^{1/p} f_1^{i_1} f_2^{i_2} \cdots f_n^{i_n} = 0$ of lower degree, a contradiction.

Comment: The point seems to be that the algebraic independence (which is essentially the injectivity of a map) satisfies fpqc descent w.r.t. the base, thus one can assume that the base is perfect (even algebraically closed).

Comment: "Choose a $k^p$-linear retraction" - Does that require the axiom of choice ("$k$ has a basis")? Can we avoid AC by considering the subfield generated by the coefficients of $g$ and $f$ ?

Comment: Yes and yes. @mr_e_man

Comment: Since $\lambda$ is not multiplicative on $k$ (unless $k$ is perfect), it's also not multiplicative on polynomials, so $\lambda$ is not well-defined on the field of fractions $k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. (But we needn't consider rational expressions anyway.)

Comment: Good point, round brackets changed to square brackets accordingly. (Did I miss any places?)